# Binding Json data to TextBlock in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting data via a REST web service and need to show the data in a list view. My problem is that I am not being able to bind the data. The error I am getting is -
Error:

```
 Error: BindingExpression path error: 'id' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>'. BindingExpression: Path='id' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Model Code :

```
    public class Deal
    {
        public String id { get; set; }            
        public string businessName { get; set; }

    }
```

XAML Code:

```
        <ListView Name="ItemData"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="640" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="396">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Width="100" FontSize="22" Text="Deal ID:"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="100" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding id}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
        </ListView>
```

CS Function:

```
        private async void MakeListData()
        {
            HttpConnection httpConnect = new HttpConnection();
            String result = await httpConnect.ReadDataFromWeb();  
            DealDataModel rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DealDataModel>(result);  
            List<Deal> dealList = rootObject.deals;
            List<string> idList = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dealList.LongCount(); i++)
            {
                idList.Add(dealList[i].id);
            }
            ItemData.ItemsSource = idList;
        }
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me overcome this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code use `List<string>` for the `ItemsSource` and `string` doesn't have property `id`, that's explain why binding engine failed to find `id` property. I guess you want to set `ItemsSource` to `dealList` which type is `List<Data>` :

```
ItemData.ItemsSource = dealList;
```